# Function compares only the first value instead of all values in an array

Tags: javascript, cycle

My function compares only the first value in the array. What is the problem?

```
var areArraySame = function(one, two){
  for(var i=0;one[i] === two[i];i++){
    return(console.log("true"));
  }
};
console.log(areArraySame([1,0,5,5,2,2] , [1,6,5,5,2,2]));
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you **return** from the for loop. **Return** breaks function execution and returns the control to the caller.

```js
var areArraySame = function(one, two){
  for(var i=0;one[i] === two[i];i++){
    console.log("true");
  }
};
areArraySame([1,0,5,5,2,2] , [1,6,5,5,2,2]);
```

And I suggest you use while `loop`, not `for`, because it will be more clear
With `while` loop

```js
var areArraySame = function(one, two){
   var index = 0;
   while(one[index] === two[index]){
     console.log("true");
     index++;
   }
};
areArraySame([1,0,5,5,2,2] , [1,6,5,5,2,2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var areArraySame = function(one, two){
  var same = true;
  for(var i=0;i < one.length;i++){
    if (one[i] !== two[i]) {
        same = false;
        break;
    }
  }

  console.log(same);
  return same;
};

console.log(areArraySame([1,0,5,5,2,2] , [1,6,5,5,2,2]));
```